# Return data (one latest object) from all the symbols passed as a list to query

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-rest-framework

I have a query like :

`EquityIntradayData.objects.using('marketdata').filter(symbol__in=symbol_list).order_by('-date_time')[:1]`

Models.py:

```
class EquityIntradayData(models.Model):
    symbol = models.CharField(db_column='SYMBOL', primary_key=True, max_length=20)  
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(db_column='DATE_TIME')  
    close = models.DecimalField(db_column='CLOSE', max_digits=10, decimal_places=5)  

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'EQUITY_INTRADAY_DATA'
        unique_together = (('symbol', 'date_time'),)
```

the return response is like:

```
[
    {
        "close": "591.00000",
        "symbol": "MPSLTD"
    }
]
```

I am filtering on a list of symbols `symbol_list = self.request.GET.getlist('symbol')`

I want it to return me data (just one latest object by date) per symbol

example: if I passed in a list of symbols : `['MPSLTD', 'SANDESH']`

I should get

```
[
    {
        "close": "591.00000",
        "symbol": "MPSLTD"
    },
   {
    "close": "783.00000",
    "symbol": "SANDESH"
 }
]
```

I tried to do distinct and earliest but was hitting a wall.
`EquityIntradayData.objects.using('marketdata').filter(symbol__in=symbol_list).distinct().earliest('date_time')`

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the symbol field inside the distinct?

```
EquityIntradayData.objects.using('marketdata').filter(symbol__in=symbol_list).distinct('symbol').order_by('-date_time')[:1]
```

Comment: I have tried that already, Issue here is that the distinct constraint not applicable to fields with mysql.

Comment: `DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend`